# Link to a record from List View

Tags: list-view

I am finishing setting up a custom app and have added a tab to show the records in a custom object. In the view, the name of the record is hyperlinked to the record itself and a column containing a person's name is also hyperlinked to take me to their person record (custom object, not Contacts).

I want to display the record ID instead and have it hyperlinked to the record instead of the record's name (indexed value enroll001, enroll002, and so on). How do I link the Record ID instead?

[image: Need to link Record ID column instead/also]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a formula field for that:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Id, Id)
```